# Need info on the JQuery Chart i found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across this neat chart being used in the 'The Guradian' Newspaper for the UK elections. Can anybody help me out and let me know where i could find more information on it. My aim is create something similar for clients data.

[Cool Chart in the Online Newspaper](http://www.theguardian.com/politics/ng-interactive/2015/may/07/election-2015-interactive-coalition-builder#?)

actual link: 
 http://www.theguardian.com/politics/ng-interactive/2015/may/07/election-2015-interactive-coalition-builder#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main script is this one, IT LOOKS like it is a custom script to me.

```
http://interactive.guim.co.uk/2015/apr/coalition-builder/assets-1430992306944/js/main.js
```